# How to overwrite all files in a folder with C#?

Tags: c#

I want to make a program in C# that replaces the text of all files in a folder.
I tried this:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Stackoverflow
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\test\folder", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            File.WriteAllText(files, "Test");
        }
    }
}
```

But I get an error that says that it cannot be converted from "string[]" to "string"
Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Hint: `File.WriteAllText` writes to a *single* file. You have *multiple* files (a string array). Apply the normal approach you would to "I want to do something for each item in a collection".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
File.WriteAllText(files, "Test");
```

try using

```
files.ForEach(file => File.WriteAllText(file, "Test"));
```

This should work.

EDIT: Or as Heinzi commented, you can similarly solve it in a loop instead of a lambda expression:

```
foreach (string file in files)
{
    File.WriteAllText(file, "Test");
}
```

Comment: Or maybe rather `foreach (string file in files) { File.WriteAllText(file, "Test"); }`? Let's not unnecessarily introduce lambda expressions to someone who struggles with simple loop constructs.

Comment: Starting them young.

Comment: @Heinzi Just say 'no' to lambdas. Dont give in to peer pressure

Comment: @pm100: Don't get me wrong, I love lambdas and LINQ. :-) That was just a didactic recommendation.

Comment: @Heinzi - i was making a stupid joke, likening lambdas to a 'gateway' feature into the 'hard stuff' like generics and await / async...

Comment: @pm100: hehe :-)